# What is the number of condensed products in each term of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider the sequence of polynomials defined by

$$a_0 = q_0$$
$$a_{n+1} = q_{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k a_{n-k}$$,

$q_j$ numeric variables (natural, integer, real, or complex). Each term $a_n$ is a sum of products of $q_j$.

So how many such products are there in each $a_n$? Naively, one may try letting $N_n$ be the number of terms, to have

$$N_0 = 1$$
$$N_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} N_k N_{n-k}$$

because there is only 1 product in the beginning, and multiplying a sum of $N_k$ products by a sum of $N_{n-k}$ products yields a sum containing $N_k N_{n-k}$ products (distributive property). This would give $N_n$ = $C_n$, the Catalan numbers.

However, it appears that there are repeated terms and factors in the sum and products which condense into products of *powers* of the $q_j$ multiplied by a coefficient number when the commutative and associative properties of multiplication are taken into account. How many such *condensed* products are there in the sequence?

In this fully-condensed form, the first few terms look like

$$a_0 = q_0$$
$$a_1 = q_1 q_0^2$$
$$a_2 = 2 q_2 q_1 q_0^3$$
$$a_3 = q_3 q_1^2 q_0^4 + 4 q_3 q_2 q_1 q_0^4$$
$$a_4 = 4 q_4 q_2 q_1^2 q_0^5 + 2 q_4 q_3 q_1^2 q_0^5 + 8 q_4 q_3 q_2 q_1 q_0^5$$
...

The coefficients multiplying the products all seem to be powers of 2. As one may expect, they sum to the Catalan numbers. The last coefficient always appears to be $2^{n-1}$. The number of condensed products in each $a_n$ forms the sequence

1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 45, 95, ...
(so the $n$th term of this sequence is the number of condensed products in $a_n$, starting at $n = 0$)

which doesn't match any in Sloane's OEIS. Note that, as one might expect, each term is not greater than the Catalan numbers.

What is this sequence of numbers?

EDIT: Taking commutativity into account, the recurrence can be written as

$$a_{n+1} = q_{n+1} \left(a_{n/2}^2 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n/2 - 1} a_k a_{n-k}\right)$$

for $n$ even, and

$$a_{n+1} = q_{n+1} \left(2 \sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} a_k a_{n-k}\right)$$

for $n$ odd. These can be combined into, where $p(n) = \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{2}$ is a parity function that returns $1$ when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd,

$$a_{n+1} = q_{n+1} \left(p(n) a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^2 + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{(n-(1 - p(n)))/2} a_k a_{n-k}\right)$$.

We note that if $a_{n/2}$ contains $N$ distinct terms condensed, then $a_{n/2}^2$ contains $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ terms. So using these formulas, we may get

$$N_0 = 1$$

For $n$ even,

$$N_{n+1} = \frac{N_{n/2}(N_{n/2}+1)}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} N_k N_{n-k}$$

For $n$ odd,

$$N_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2} N_k N_{n-k}$$.

This sequence seems to bound the true number of terms more tightly, but still isn't equal to it. Not to mention I have no idea about a closed form for this...

Comment: Hi, What are the $q_n$s ? Are $q_0, q_1, q_2, \ldots$ all different or same ? How did you get the sequence $1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 45, 95\ldots$ ?

Comment: $q_j$ are just numeric variables, so they can be anything you want. The sequence is the number of condensed products of $q_j$ in each $a_n$.

Comment: Looks quite difficult, even guessing routines couldn't find any generating function, functional equation etc. Here are some more terms if anyone wants it: $1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 6 , 11 , 23 , 45 , 95 , 194 , 414 , 863 , 1850 , 3910 , 8413 , 17887, \ldots$